# efficient way to read huge tables (over 600 million rows and around 27 GB) in R

Tags: r, data.table, multicore, fread

I have a huge txt file with over 600 million rows and around 27 GB. I used the fread from data.table on a server with 256GB RAM and 32 processors. It took around 3.5 hours to complete reading 10% of the data. In that case, to only read in this table, it will take around 35 hours on my server. What is the faster way to read such big dataset?
1) split it into multiple small files first, and read in?
2) does multicore work for the fread?

Any suggestions and comments are appreciated!

Comment: May I ask what you plan to do with this data once you have loaded it into R?  Even on a server with 256GB RAM, manipulating your entire 27GB data set could be pushing the limits.

Comment: Have you considered using a database option, such as `RMySQL`?

Comment: Provide more details, 3.5h using fread? If you are able to split file into few pieces you can try to use fread in parallel using `Rserve`, it is basically what I've made in [big.data.table](https://github.com/jangorecki/big.data.table) package. It also allows to split processing into multiple nodes/machines in parallel. You can have it without the package just by `Rserve` + `RSclient` + `lapply`.

Comment: Are you sure that you are not running into a hardware i/o limitation? `fread` can read 2.7 GB of data almost instantaneously.

Comment: Not enough information - I've read in 50Gb files in a matter of minutes before, so something is fishy about the OP. Maybe add a small sample of your data.

Comment: @Roland hardware i/o? the only scenario I can imagine is network storage on a very slow network - and that can be easily tested by doing smth like `wc -l filename`

Comment: @eddi That's exactly what I'm suspecting.

Comment: 600M? What do these rows contain, Facebook's passwords? :P

Answer (score 4):

We need to see a sample of the data and also the output of `fread(...,verbose=TRUE)` as requested in [point 7 on the support page](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Support). I agree with the comments that it feels likes something is wrong. It is possible for R's hash algorithm to be defeated and for data to *never* load (using any method), as demonstrated by Pall Melsted [here](https://twitter.com/pmelsted/status/628998506527780865). Maybe something like that is happening if you have some dense hex keys in a not-real-world-data file, perhaps.

To answer the question (if H2O is acceptable), my testing on a 23GB .csv with 9 columns and 500m rows showed `h2o.importFile` to take 50s compared to `fread` at 300s; i.e. 6 times faster. See slides 18-20 on [Presentations](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Presentations) page or direct link [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/talks/LondonR_201506.pdf). H2O feels like R (or Python) but just has a Java backend rather than a C backend. `h2o.importFile()` is parallel, distributed and compresses the data in memory too.

When PayPal tested on their data they found `h2o.importFile()` to be 10 times faster than `fread()`. See 19:00-20:00 in [this video](http://library.fora.tv/2015/11/10/big_data_machine_learning_with_r_nachum_shacham).

Other parallel solutions that I know of are the SparkR package (e.g. [this question for reading files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31157649/reading-text-file-in-sparkr-1-4-0)) which I haven't yet tested or timed and @jangorecki's new [big.data.table](https://github.com/jangorecki/big.data.table) package which looks very promising.

Comment: But how do you only read selected columns or rows with h2o.importFile() ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there is a thread-safe variant of fread but remember: to get safety you give away speed.

Reading using multiple cores is a waste of time, as is reading the records one by one:

```
if (fread (buffer, reclen, 600000000, infile) ...
```

This variant will perform 600000000 logical reads (reads from internal buffers) and not quite as many physical reads (actually reading the disk).
If the records are of equal length:

```
if (fread (buffer, reclen * 600000000, 1, infile) ...
```

You will save an enormous amount of overhead, which you also will with a compromise:

```
i = 0;
while (i<600000000)
{
  fread (buffer+i*reclen, reclen * 1000, 1, infile);
  i += 1000;
}
```

This compromise cuts overhead 99.9% but you will still need to loop 600000 times. Read 10000 at a time? 60000? Experiment!

Answer (score 0):

It's worth considering the recently (2021) released [vroom package](https://vroom.r-lib.org/). Its web page claims the following benchmarks:

| package | version | time (sec) | speedup | throughput |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| vroom | 1.3.0 | 1.11 | 67.13 | 1.48 GB/sec |
| data.table | 1.13.0 | 13.12 | 5.67 | 125.19 MB/sec |
| readr | 1.3.1 | 32.57 | 2.28 | 50.41 MB/sec |
| read.delim | 4.0.2 | 74.37 | 1.00 | 22.08 MB/sec |

(Although comments on the original post suggest that the R package machinery may not be the bottleneck, because reading 2.7 Gb with `data.table::fread()` *should* have been fast even in 2015.)